# how to debug the $rootScope object of angularjs in the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way of debugging the angularjs application when it is loaded in the browser?

ie. I wish to get the `$rootScope` of my current application. How would I do that?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

+1 for Batarang

Also, you can get the scope from any element in the DOM by executing the following from the console

```
angular.element(DOMNODE).scope()
```

Where DOMNODE, is of course, a reference to a DOM node.

For example, in Chrome in the **elements** tab you can select the node where the `ng-app` directive is, and get the root scope with

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

Comment: +1 For chrome's $0 for the selected div. you can also use $1, $2 for the previously selected element.

Comment: Using the same selector you can select the `ng-app` element then do `var $rootScope = angular.element($0).injector().get('$rootScope')` and play with it.

Comment: Example `angular.element('body').scope();` in case of your app is `<body data-ng-app="SomeApp">`

Comment: It's worth nothing that to `debugInfoEnabled` can't be disabled for this.

Answer (score 47):

In the developer console try this

```
$rootScope = angular.element(document).scope()
```

Answer (score 16):

[Batarang](http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/introducing-angularjs-batarang.html) -- A Google Chrome plugin for AngularJS

After you installed this, you can do

console.log($rootScope);

and check the scope object in your chrome console.

BTW, if you want to get $rootScope, you need to inject to your controller

like

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

}
```

Answer (score 5):

In developer console type `angular.element('body').scope();` in case of your app is `<body data-ng-app="SomeApp">`

Comment: you can use '[ng-app]' instead of body so it becomes universal

Answer (score 4):

For those using `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` and `ng-strict-di` just paste this in the console and `$rootScope` will be logged and added to `window`:

```
function getRootScope($rootScope){ console.log(window.$rootScope = $rootScope); }
getRootScope.$inject = ["$rootScope"];
angular.element(document.querySelector('[data-ng-app],[ng-app]')).injector().invoke(getRootScope);
```

Comment: This is awsome. And should probably be considered a security issue for Angularjs :)

Comment: This wouldn't work if AngularJS didn't expose itself to window. So I guess you can just call `delete window.angular`, hopefully it doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the $rootScope in your sources Developer Tools->Sources

[image: $rootScope]

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add that there is a free Chrome Extension called "Angular Scope Inspector" ([current store url](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-scope-inspector/aaglpchhlnofjbbpopfdfgllfkhnljnl)) that will automatically inspect scope of selected elements in the developer tools elements tab

I just discovered it today, and it's very useful, IMO