# Can't access $rootScope from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Why can't I access the `$rootScope`, particulary the currentUser object and the `signedIn()` function from the RegistrationController?

I'm trying to follow a tutorial example and I'm able to sucessfully set the `$rootScope.currentUser` variable in a service (Authentication), but when I try to access it from another controller (RegistrationController) I cannot access it.

My understanding is that `$rootScope` is kind of a global variable that is accessible from all the app, is this correct?

```
myApp.controller('RegistrationController', 
    function($scope, $firebaseAuth, $location, Authentication, $rootScope){

    $scope.login = function() {
        Authentication.login($scope.user)
        .then(function(userReturned){
            console.log('registration.js: logged in user '+userReturned.uid);
            //console.log('registration.js: $rootScope.currentUser ahora es... ');
            //console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
            $location.path('/meetings');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            $scope.message = error.toString();
        });
    } //login


}); //RegistrationController

myApp.factory('Authentication', 
    function($firebase, $firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL, $location, $rootScope) {
    // using $firebaseAuth instead of SimpleLogin 

    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    var myObject = {
        login : function(user) {

            return authObj.$authWithPassword({
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            })
            .then(function(authData){ 
                console.log('authentication.js: logged in user '+ authData.uid);

                var userRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users/' + authData.uid);
                var userObj = $firebase(userRef).$asObject();

                userObj.$loaded().then(function() {
                    $rootScope.currentUser = userObj;
                });

                $rootScope.$broadcast('$firebaseAuth:authWithPassword',authData); // avisa al scope

              return authData;
          });
        }, //login

        signedIn: function() {
            //console.log(authObj);
            //console.log('authentication.js: signedIn function called and returned '+ (authObj.user != null) );
            return authObj.user != null;
        } // signedIn

    } //myObject

    // add signedIn to the $rootScope
    $rootScope.signedIn = function() {
        return myObject.signedIn();
    }

    return myObject;
});
```

Comment: Firstly, provide some plunkr or js fiddle example. Also, it is not good idea to write to any of scopes (and to rootScope too) scalars (do it throught objects, i.e. $scope.model.XXX). Another thing: its is not good idea to store anything in rootScope at all, store data in services instead: you can  them access from any "ANYTHING" (i.e. controller, directive etc). And yes, rootScope is kind of global scope in AngularJS (like global variables). Do you remember it is bad to use them? Same situation with rootScope.Don't use it to store variables.

Comment: Hi @Sharikov Vladislav, thanks for the comment. I did some research before asking and I found what you mention about services, but I'm following a tutorial where they use $rootScope and it seemed strange that I wasn't able to read the value I stored there. I know that using global variables is not a good idea :)

I'm not very familiar with Plunker but I'll give it a try and edit with the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what's happening is the promise Authentication.login is being resolved before currentUser being set $rootScope.currentUser = userObj;

to make sure this is the case, try put a breakpoint on this line in your Authentication service:

```
$rootScope.currentUser = userObj;
```

and another breakpoint on this one in your controller:

```
console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
```

and see which one is being executed before the other.

IF this is the case, try this:
Move the block of code in [THEN] statement from your service to your controller, where you are treating the current user and logging it.

Comment: you were correct in regards to the execution time of the different parts of the code. A comment for future reference that got me confused, is that even when the `$rootScope.currentUser` was correctly set (either in the controller or the service), I was unable to access the $rootScope variable from Chrome Dev Console.

Comment: I found this question/answer that clarifies the subject...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170732/how-to-debug-the-rootscope-object-of-angularjs-when-in-the-browser/13170943#13170943

You can either use Batarang chrome plugin, or the following code to get the values stored in $rootScope.

`$rootScope = angular.element(document).scope()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to print $rootScope.currentUser from RegistrationController.login(). But currentUser was never set on $rootScope. Here's an example that demonstrates using $rootScope on two controllers.

```
angular.module('Main', [])
  .controller("SetCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.name = 'abc';
    $rootScope.copy = $scope.name;
  })
  .controller("GetCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.fromSetCtrl = $rootScope.copy;
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dj6Y9hIEJ3KA9yAjuQP5

Comment: Hi @restassured, in the Authentication service you can find this code where an object is assigned to $rootScope ...

`userObj.$loaded().then(function() {
                    $rootScope.currentUser = userObj;
                });`

That code gets executed in the `$scope.login` function of the RegistrationController. When I try to print  `$rootScope.currentUser ` using  `console.log() ` from the controller, I get an undefined value for that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure how your are using your service/factory and how your apps and controllers are set up.

I think $rootScope is the "top" scope of the outermost controller of your app.   You can have a $rootScope for each of your "app".

I would guess that if you set a variable in the $rootScope in the service in one of your app and then try to access your service from the $rootScope from the controller from ANOTHER app, you will not be able to find the variable because it is in another $rootScope.  **In that sense $rootScope is NOT a global variable.**

You can access $rootScope variables directly from the child controllers if you pass in "$rootScope" when you define your controller, or from indirectly from $scope of the child controllers, because angular will look for the variable from the current controller's scope all the way up to that controller's $rootScope.

Hope this helps.